# How to sent message at various number separate by ";"?

Tags: java, android

```java
private void sendSMS(){
    String phoneNo = number.getText().toString().trim();
    String SMS = message.getText().toString().trim();
    if (number.getText().toString().length() >= 4) {
        if (!message.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            SmsManager smsManager =sManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, SMS, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your SMS is sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter a message!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The number is incorrect, it must contain at least 4 numbers!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I have this piece of code that works successfully! But I want now sent message to various numbers with separate ";".

For example, in the emulator I want enter in the numbers zone (`1254;2058;153348`) and the message has to be sent to all the contacts I have enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **phoneNo** contains the following value: 1254;2058;153348
You can split your phone numbers to array with numbers.
Please see the following example:

```
String phoneNo = number.getText().toString().trim();
String []phoneNumbers = phoneNo.split(";");
```

After that you can iterate by every element in **phoneNumbers** array

Answer (score 0):

I want just sent the same message at various numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you split string on ; and than iterate through loop to send it one by one

I hope you understand what i mean